# Susy grid and CSS reset

Tags: grid, sass, reset

I want to use Compass's Global Reset module to reset all the default browser styles. My configuration is SASS version: Sass 3.2.10 (Media Mark), Compass version: Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam), SUSY Grid version: susy-1.0.9. I don't want to use Normalize css by Nicolas Gallagher. I have to support IE 6 and newer browsers on desktop, tablet, mobile. 
This is the first time I will be using Susy grid and learning. I want to know is the global reset module of compass fully compatiable with Susy grid ?

(Please, forgive me for the poor English.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Any** reset or normalization should work with Susy. So yes, the Compass default is fully compatible.